# How to create Uri pointing to an local image in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I was wondering if it is allowed to read local images within a Silverlight client. (it is just to test a control)

```
var image = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("../Images/2.jpg", UriKind.Relative) };
```

Would this Uri be allowed and the image created? For some reason the picture doesn't show, despite getting no compiler errors that the Uri might have been wrong...

Thanks for advice,
kave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your project looks like this

```
 - Project
      - Images
           - 2.jpg
      - Another_Folder
           - *your code file*
```

, that should be fine.

---

Remember that

```
../Images/2.jpg
```

is navigating to parent folder, then looking for an Images folder and a 2.jpg file.